# EC2 instance has spikes of very high latency with simple test application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, latency

It's a simple React Native app with a NodeJS server on Elastic Beanstalk / Auto-Scaled EC2, using MongoDB Atlas as database (mongoose).

Latency tends to be low but somehow it occassionally spikes to multi-second latency when I'm the only one testing the application and there are like 30 documents total in the entire database...

Latency spikes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do8Rx.jpg

How can the latency be so high? Sometimes my emulator is very slow but that's on the client side, not (AWS) server side, so I think that should not impact my EC2 latency? Maybe I am not completely clear on what factors can influence latency, either

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question given the information provided. You need to check other things like EC2 CPU usage, MongoDB Atlas CPU usage, DB slow query logs, etc. to determine exactly what the bottleneck is. A performance tracking tool like NewRelic would help a lot in this scenario.

Comment: @MarkB Here are some more AWS monitoring metrics: https://imgur.com/a/OCRjtQp . Max network in and out (~700 KB isn't that much though right...?), and CPU usage, tend to coincide with the latency jump. I'm really not sure what AWS classifies as 'latency' because my queries & app appear quite fine. Mongo free tier doesn't tell me CPU usage but should be low given miniscule volume of documents...

Comment: Maybe the large Network In is from new instances doing npm install or something ... In any case, I still don't understand why latency is so high

Comment: Have you checked the MongoDB metrics that correspond to the same time frame? As it is there still isn't nearly enough information here for anybody to tell you what is going on. You need to dig into this in much more detail, and ideally instrument your application with something like NewRelic or DataDog that can help you quickly pinpoint your performance problems.